# How to change UILabel text dynamically?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change my UILabel's text. 
But the text is the same for the 3 labels so I'm wondering if I can do something like store an instance of the relevant UILabel and write a generic string format to change the text.

So these are my IBOutlet:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *pushupDetails;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *situpDetails;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *runDetails;
```

This is what I hope to achieve (simplified):

```
-(void)updateDetailText:(NSArray *)results station:(int)station {
  UILabel *templabel;
  switch (station) {
      case 0:
          templabel = [self.pushupDetails mutableCopy];
          break;
      case 1:
          templabel = [self.situpDetails mutableCopy];
          break;
      case 2:
          templabel = [self.runDetails mutableCopy];
          break;
      default:
          break;
  }

  templabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You need %d - %d reps", 10, 50];
}
```

However, the program crash with

```
 -[UILabel mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b82b920
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UILabel mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10b82b920'
```

the moment the mutableCopy is ran. Is it possible to achieve what I want, or do I have to write every single text change individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UILabel` doesn't conforms to `NSCopying` class, because of that you can't use `copy` OR `mutableCopy`.

You have to use like below example

```
switch (station) {
      case 0:
          templabel = self.pushupDetails;
          break;
      case 1:
          templabel = self.situpDetails;
          break;
      case 2:
          templabel = self.runDetails;
          break;
      default:
          break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each label the tags 0, 1, and 2.

Then change the method like this:

```
-(void)updateDetailText:(NSArray *)results station:(int)station
{    
  ((UILabel *) [self viewWithTag:station]).text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You need %d - %d reps", 10, 50];;
}
```

Or, you can try in each case test, to use the usual assignment:

```
templabel = pushupDetails;
```

because you need to reference the actual object, not a copy of it.